# Convert Text file to XML file (title && url)

Tags: xml, awk

I have a text file that i am exporting links to formatted like this

```
Cover-ups http://example.com/1
One-pieces http://example.com/2
Sarongs http://example.com/3
```

How can i use a `awk` command or something similar to format it like so

```
<link>
  <title>Cover-ups</title>
  <url>http://example.com/1</url>
</link>

<link>
  <title>One-pieces</title>
  <url>http://example.com/2</url>
</link>

<link>
  <title>Sarongs</title>
  <url>http://example.com/3</url>
</link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

**Turning the Data into XML**

http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/converting-data-to-xml-with-awk.html

This should get you started:

```
BEGIN { 
   FS="|";
   printf("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n");
}

NF==1 {
   printf("<link>\n");   
   split($1, a, " "); for (i in a) {
    if (i == 1)
        printf("<url>%s</url>\n", a[2]);
    if (i == 2)
        printf("<title>%s</title>\n", a[1]);
   }
   printf("</link>\n");   
}

END {
}
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<link>
    <title>Cover-ups</title>
    <url>http://example.com/1</url>
</link>
<link>
    <title>One-pieces</title>
    <url>http://example.com/2</url>
</link>
<link>
    <title>Sarongs</title>
    <url>http://example.com/3</url>
</link>
```

Comment: I ended up getting my own solution thanks to the document you linked thanks a lot. please edit it back in if you get the chance

Comment: @gotnull, changing FS to | and splitting by hand using the default FS is not very clear approach...

Answer (score 1):

Your text file:

```
nampt@nampt-desktop:/mnt$ cat 1
Cover-ups http://example.com/1
One-pieces http://example.com/2
Sarongs http://example.com/3
```

My shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
tmp1=$(echo $line|awk '{print $1}')
tmp2=$(echo $line|awk '{print $2}')

cat >> output << EOF
<link>
  <title>${tmp1}</title>
  <url>${tmp2}</url>
</link>

EOF
done < 1
```

Output

```
nampt@nampt-desktop:/mnt$ cat output

<link>
  <title>Cover-ups</title>
  <url>http://example.com/1</url>
</link>

<link>
  <title>One-pieces</title>
  <url>http://example.com/2</url>
</link>

<link>
  <title>Sarongs</title>
  <url>http://example.com/3</url>
</link>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1:** Just another Awk oneliner:

```
awk '{printf "<link>\n<title>%s</title>\n<url>%s</url>\n</link>\n\n",$1,$2}'
```

**2:** In a similar situation I used a Perl version following Awk philosophy (this time producing a valid XML)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -na

use XML::Writer::Simple tags => [qw/refs link title url/], partial=>1 ;

BEGIN{ print xml_header,start_refs; }
     { print link(title($F[0]),url($F[1])),"\n";}
END  { print end_refs; }
```

producing:

```
$perl links2xml mylinks

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<refs>
<link><title>Cover-ups</title><url>http://example.com/1</url></link>
<link><title>One-pieces</title><url>http://example.com/2</url></link>
<link><title>Sarongs</title><url>http://example.com/3</url></link>
</refs>
```

Option `-na` makes perl behave in a Awk way (
`while(line=<>){F=split(line); BODY}`)

If necessary install the module using cpan(`sudo cpan XML::Writer::Simple`), apt-get or similar